# SQL query returning 'Overload resolution error'

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, oledb

I have a readini file to connect to my SQL Server table, and in my query code to display data from it, I'm getting an error that I've not been able to solve, is there anybody here who can?

This is the error:

> Error 1
>   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments: 
>   'Public Sub New(selectCommandText As String, selectConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)': Value of type 'SQLServerApplication.readini' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'.
>   'Public Sub New(selectCommandText As String, selectConnectionString As String)': Value of type 'SQLServerApplication.readini' cannot be converted to 'String'.

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmViewDtb


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connection As readini = New readini()
    connection.getConnectionString()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblPerson"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "tblPerson")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblPerson"

End Sub
End Class
```

The line that the error is occurring on is line 13:

```
 Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
```

Code for getConnectionString;

```
    Public Function getConnectionString() As String

    Dim s As String =
        "Provider=" & provider & ";" &
        "user ID=" & username & ";" &
        "password=" & password & ";" &
        "initial catalog=" & databasename & ";" &
        "data source=" & servername & "; " &
    "Persists Security Info=False"

End Function
```

Thanks in advance if you can get it!

Comment: So what does your `readini` class look like, and which constructor are you expecting to call here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting the error as the constructor for OleDbDataAdpater is expecting two strings and your `connection` variable isn't a string.  I suspect your code needs to look like this:

```
Dim connection As readini = New readini()
Dim ConnString = connection.getConnectionString()

Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblPerson"
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ConnString)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds, "tblPerson")
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblPerson"
```

The getConnectionString method also needed amending to add the `Return` statement:

```
Public Function getConnectionString() As String

    Dim s As String =
        "Provider=" & provider & ";" &
        "user ID=" & username & ";" &
        "password=" & password & ";" &
        "initial catalog=" & databasename & ";" &
        "data source=" & servername & "; " &
        "Persists Security Info=False"
    Return s
End Function
```

Comment: That solved the compilation error that I was having, but now I get a runtime error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: That sounds like you're not getting back a valid connection string from your readini class. Use the debugger or a Debug.Print to display the contents of ConnString.  It might be worth adding the code for your getConnectionString method to your question so we can help with that.

Comment: I'll try stepping through it now, meanwhile I've now posted the getConnectionString code in the original question if you'd like to see it.

Comment: OK, that helps.  You're not returning the value of s from getConnectionString.  Just add a 'Return s' before the 'End Function' line

Comment: Of course! Yes, okay this worked, thank you! I'll be sure to accept your answer as soon as I'm able to.